# FirstNonRepeatingCharacter in a given string In java using time Complexity O(n)

Tags: java, time-complexity

if i have given a string like "aabefddbccffaa" the program should return a character which is firstNonRepeatingCharacter in the string, example output is "e". Time complexity should be O(n) only. I have tried with HashMaps and using character array.

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> char_counts = new HashMap(); 
for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) { 
    char c = string.charAt(i); 
    if(char_counts.containsKey(c)) { 
        char_counts.put(c, char_counts.get(c)+1); 
    } else { 
        char_counts.put(c, 1); 
    } 
} 
for (int i=0; i<string.length();i++) { 
    char c = string.charAt(i); 
    if (char_counts.get(c) == 1) {
         return c; 
    }
} 
return '';
```

[Note] If there is no FirstNonRepeatingCharacter not found just return '';

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I agree with Eran. Your code is _O(n)_, so other than the compilation error on the last return statement, your code seems fine. Why aren't you satisfied with your own code?

Comment: @Andreas i have written first  forloop for storing the characters and count.These HashMaps aren't sorted so we can't get the firstNonRepeatingCharacter and there is no ordering in HashMaps but luckily HashMap put and get time complexity is O(1).  so the second forloop is to return the FirstNonRepeating character. But for this Complexity is like O(2n) anyway we can drop the constants. I just to know is there any optimal solution can anyone found for this.

Comment: @harithapagadam *"there is no ordering in HashMaps"* Correct, but there is in `LinkedHashMap`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089611/5221149).

Comment: @harithapagadam *"is there any optimal solution?"* Your code is very close, but can be improved slightly. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089611/5221149) for how to reduce the number of iterations needed by the second loop. Other than that, it's minute improvements that JIT might take care of anyway, like not boxing `char` into `Character` multiple times.

Comment: @Andreas i have tried one more solution like using string inbuilt functions using indexOf() and lastIndexOf().

Comment: @harithapagadam That would definitely not be _O(n)_. Use what you already have in the question, or use the improvement I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are concerned about the second loop, even though it doesn't affect the `O(n)` asymptotic time complexity.

You can still get rid of it.

For example, instead of finding the frequency of each character, you can maintain two `Set`s - the first - `all` - contains all the distinct characters. The second - `uniques` - contains only the non repeating characters.

You can build these two `Set`s in a single loop. After that loop, you return the first `Character` in the `uniques` `Set`. I used `LinkedHashSet` for `uniques`, so that you'll get the first non repeating character (which is the first character added to that `Set` that wasn't later removed).

```
Set<Character> all = new HashSet<>(); 
Set<Character> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) { 
    char c = string.charAt(i); 
    if (all.add(c)) { // returns true if this is the first time c appears in the String
        uniques.add(c); 
    } else { // c already appeared in the String
        uniques.remove(c);
    } 
} 
return uniques.isEmpty () ? ' ' : uniques.iterator().next();
```

Comment: For full Unicode support, e.g. for emojis, replace `Character`/`char` with `Integer`, replace `i++` with `i += string.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1)`, and replace `string.charAt(i)` with `string.codePointAt(i)`

Answer (score 2):

Build a frequency-map using a `LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>`, then iterate the map until you find the first one with a frequency count of 1. You must use a `LinkedHashMap` so that if there is more than one non-repeating character, they will be in the map in the same order as in the input string. Building the map is *O(n)* (amortized), and finding the non-repeating character is *O(n)*, so the overall complexity is *O(n)*.

Better yet, use Streams to build a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long>`, where the key is a Unicode Code Point. That way your solution can handle characters from the supplemental planes, such as Emojis.

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
```

```
static String firstNonRepeatingCharacter(String text) {
    return text.codePoints().boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .findFirst()
        .map(e -> Character.toString(e.getKey()))
        .orElse("");
}
```

The code above requires Java 11+. For Java 8+, use:

```
        .map(e -> new String(new int[] { e.getKey() }, 0, 1))
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(firstNonRepeatingCharacter("aabefddbccffaa"));
System.out.println(firstNonRepeatingCharacter("aabefddbccffaae"));
System.out.println(firstNonRepeatingCharacter("aabefddbccffaae"));
```

*Output*

```
e
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
public class FirstNonRepeatingCharacter {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String str = "information";
        System.out.println(getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(str));
    }

    private static char getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(String str) {
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (str.indexOf(c) == str.lastIndexOf(c)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Output:

`f`